# ActiveMQ - Alternate messages stuck in the Queue

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, message-queue

Facing a weird issue related to ActiveMQ.
1. Have setup a simple queue for processing the incoming request.
2. Able to send the message successfully to the Queue.
3. When I check the message in the admin portal, it shows under the Enqueued message.
4. But the Consumer never got the message from the Queue.
5. When I submit the second request, the request gets dequeued.
**6. The problem is with the previous message being lost and considered by ActiveMQ as dequeued.**

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do the message get sent with expiration set? TTL